# Merging one column of data throughout rest of database

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that look something like this

```
ID     Math    Chem   HoursAvailable
1      Math    NA      3:00-4:00
2      NA      Chem    4:00-5:00
3      Math    Chem    12:00-2:00
```

And I am trying to merge the hours available into the row so it looks like this

```
ID     Math        Chem         HoursAvailable
1      3:00-4:00   NA           3:00-4:00
2      NA          4:00-5:00    4:00-5:00
3      12:00-2:00  12:00-2:00   12:00-2:00
```

I cant get the data to merge without overwriting all of the NA values. I have also tried separating the HoursAvailable into a separate dataframe and then attempting to merge. I have also tried using tidyverse, but have been unable to do it.

Comment: I think you're working with data frames, not a database?

Comment: You are correct, I accidentally used the wrong term. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Seems like a straight forward `ifelse` problem, you could just use something like `mutate(df, Math = ifelse(is.na(Math), NA, HoursAvailable))`

Comment: @KevinArseneau it would be, but the actual database has many different columns and I dont know how to do it without discretely naming the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` way to do it using `gather` and `spread` from the `tidyr` package. Note this is probably only useful if you have many variables you need to get the `HoursAvailable` merged into.  Otherwise something like @KevinArseneau has suggested in the comments using base R will be much simpler.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("ID     Math    Chem   HoursAvailable
1      Math    NA      3:00-4:00
2      NA      Chem    4:00-5:00
3      Math    Chem    12:00-2:00")


df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(ID, HoursAvailable)) %>% 
  mutate(value = if_else(is.na(value), value, HoursAvailable)) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  select(ID, Math, Chem, HoursAvailable)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      ID       Math       Chem HoursAvailable
#> * <int>      <chr>      <chr>          <chr>
#> 1     1  3:00-4:00       <NA>      3:00-4:00
#> 2     2       <NA>  4:00-5:00      4:00-5:00
#> 3     3 12:00-2:00 12:00-2:00     12:00-2:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
df[,c('Math', 'Chem')][!is.na(df[,c('Math', 'Chem')])]=df[,c('HoursAvailable','HoursAvailable')][!is.na(df[,c('Math', 'Chem')])]

df
  ID       Math       Chem HoursAvailable
1  1  3:00-4:00       <NA>      3:00-4:00
2  2       <NA>  4:00-5:00      4:00-5:00
3  3 12:00-2:00 12:00-2:00     12:00-2:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::mutate` and `ifelse` to get to your data structure.

```
library(dplyr)
# example data
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Math = c("Math", NA, "Math"), 
                                Chem = c(NA, "Chem", "Chem"), 
                                HoursAvailable = c("3:00-4:00", "4:00-5:00", "12:00-2:00")),
                                .Names = c("ID", "Math", "Chem", "HoursAvailable"), 
                                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Math = ifelse(is.na(Math), NA, HoursAvailable), 
         Chem = ifelse(is.na(Chem), NA, HoursAvailable))

  ID       Math       Chem HoursAvailable
1  1  3:00-4:00       <NA>      3:00-4:00
2  2       <NA>  4:00-5:00      4:00-5:00
3  3 12:00-2:00 12:00-2:00     12:00-2:00
```

However, I'd take it a step further to create a *tidy* data frame: one with subjects in one column and hours in another.

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Math = ifelse(is.na(Math), NA, HoursAvailable), 
         Chem = ifelse(is.na(Chem), NA, HoursAvailable)) %>% 
  select(-HoursAvailable) %>% 
  gather(subject, hours, -ID)

  ID subject      hours
1  1    Math  3:00-4:00
2  2    Math       <NA>
3  3    Math 12:00-2:00
4  1    Chem       <NA>
5  2    Chem  4:00-5:00
6  3    Chem 12:00-2:00
```

You could also add `%>% na.omit()` to the end, to remove rows with `NA`.